# GoogleApiClient is not connecting in alpha testing mode, but it does in development mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, google-api-client, android-youtube-api

GoogleApiClient is not connecting in alpha testing mode, but it does in development mode.

`mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();`

When checking if the google API is connected or not, it always shows not connected.

```
if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() || Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) == null)
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: are you calling public abstract void onConnected (Bundle connectionHint)

Comment: I didn't get you clearly. Could you please elaborate?  I have below code : `@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 125; //GET_ACCOUNTS`

Comment: `if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    int hasWriteContactsPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, (Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS));
                    if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
                                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                
            }`

Comment: Please edit your question first

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputations to edit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123 is for GET_ACCOUNTS